# Hapi route validation with Joi for Form Data

Tags: reactjs, form-data, joi, hapi

I have a use case where I need to send an array of files to my Hapi backend. The best way I found to do this from my React client is using FormData. This approach has been working great while on an older version of Hapi and Joi (`"hapi": "^17.8.1"`, `"joi": "^13.7.0"`). However, after upgraded my Hapi and Joi (`"@hapi/hapi": "^20.2.1"`, `"joi": "^17.5.0"`) I'm having an issue with Joi rejecting the files array with `"files[]" must be an array`. Any idea why this would be happening now after updating? I have tried using Joi.object as the payload validation but that also gave the same result.

Below is my form data code:

```
const form = new FormData();

form.append('title', this.state.title);

this.state.files && this.state.files.map((item) => {
   form.append("files[]", item.file);
   return true;
});
```

Below is my Hapi Route:

```
{
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/files',
    handler: files.save,
    options: {
        auth: 'jwt',
        validate: {
            payload: {
                title: Joi.string().required(),
                files: Joi.array().items(Joi.any())
            }
        },
        payload: {
            maxBytes: 1048576 * 100,
            output: 'stream',
            parse: true,
            timeout: 60000,
            multipart: true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use allow: 'multipart/form-data', and after your code update the object payload should look like this.

```
payload: {
        maxBytes: 1048576 * 100,
        output: 'stream',
        parse: true,
        timeout: 60000,
        multipart: true,
        allow: 'multipart/form-data',
    }
```